# Apache Airflow is inconsistent with getting the google-cloud-bigquery versions installed on the gcp compute engine instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, airflow

I am using the Apache Airflow version 1.8.1.

We have two GCP instances  master and worker where we have installed some specific versions of GCP. 
The version installed for google-cloud-bigquery is 1.6.0 on both instances .

A piece of code bring in error of version for google-cloud-bigquery.

```
bigquery_client = bigquery.Client()
dataset_ref = bigquery_client.dataset(dataset, project=project)
tables = list(bigquery_client.list_tables(dataset_ref))
```

**Error message:**
tables = list(bigquery_client.list_tables(dataset_ref))
{bash_operator.py:94} INFO - AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'list_tables'

Added the pip freeze command to check which version is being picked and found whenever the version 0.26.0 is picked , the code fails but works fine with 1.6.0.

I have never installed version 0.26.0 for google-cloud-bigquery , unable to debug how it gets picked up and from which machine.

Comment: Apache Airflow 1.8.1 is too old and outdated. Please use 1.9.0 at the least or 1.10.2 if possible

Comment: @kaxil - For current implementation I am looking for a fix. Is it because of  airflow version , this error is occuring ? Though it seems a different issue and not version issue

Comment: Airflow doesn't install `google-cloud-bigquery` package. It only installs `google-api-python-client`. So your error might be because of a manual install of it.
https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.8.1/setup.py#L135-L139

Comment: @kaxil - if I run the command ,' source activate airflow' , the google-cloud-bigquery version gets list as 1.6.0 . 
But if without running the above command , run pip freeze |grep google-cloud-bigquery , the version gets listed as 0.26.0

Comment: @Neha0909 - that is because someone must have installed that package in that virtualenv. Your airflow setup should run in the virtual environment and it should pick up whatever you have installed in that virtual environment. Update the packages wherever needed. Point being: airflow doesn't install it be default.